# error: 'QObject' is an ambiguous base of 'SerialPort' QObject::connect(&uartObj, SIGNAL(readDone(QByteArray)), this, SLOT(hdlRxDone(QByteArray)));

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, serial-port

I want to create `SerialPort` class,
and it can receive msg automatic and then emit a signal.

but when I compile it show the error message:

> error: 'QObject' is an ambiguous base of 'SerialPort'
>        QObject::connect(&uartObj, SIGNAL(readDone(QByteArray)), this, SLOT(hdlRxDone(QByteArray)));

have someone can help me to solve it ?
thanks.

```
#ifndef SERIALPORT_H
#define SERIALPORT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QThread>

class SerialPort : public QSerialPort, public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SerialPort(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SerialPort();
    void stop();

signals:
    void readDone(QByteArray data);

public slots:

private:
    void run();
};

#endif // SERIALPORT_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `QSerialPort` and `QThread` derived from `QObject`, so in your code you have multiple inheritance from `QObject`, which is forbidden in `Qt`. You should derive only from `QThread`, but it is not very good way. The best way is to create simple `Worker` class derived from `QObject`, which `HAS` `QSerialPort`, and move this class to some thread with `moveToThread()`.

You can find more information about correct usage [here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) or in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details).

Full example about serial port in separate thread you can find [here](http://we.easyelectronics.ru/electro-and-pc/qthread-qserialport-krutim-v-otdelnom-potoke-rabotu-s-som-portom.html), it is in russian language, but you need only code which is not very complex.